# Sybase extension doesn't work

Tags: php, iis, sybase

I'm currently working on a project that has to write to both MSSQL and a Sybase database.
I'm working on a Microsoft Server 2008 R2 server with IIS 7 and PHP installed (cause I've got to work in PHP.)

When in IIS-management I go to the PHP manager, and try to activate the sybase extension (php_sybase_ct.dll). It gets transferred to the activated group, but when I run my script I keep getting "undefined function sybase_pconnect();"

What am I doing wrong? The .dll is in place, it is activated in the .ini file. What is the problem?

Hope someone can help me, cause from looking around the internet, I've seen a lot of problems with PHP and sybase.

Comment: Do you have the Sybase client libraries installed? Otherwise the DLL probably won't load due to dependencies.

Comment: what is meant with 'Sybase client libraries' exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [PHP client download page](http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=1019698) for Sybase states

> The PHP modules require SQL Anywhere 10.0.1.3767 or greater.*

You can download the SQL Anywhere database client [here](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-35857).

If the SQL Anywhere client libraries are missing (or not found by PHP), you'd get exactly the symptoms you're getting.